# a one-to-one and onto function that cannot be continuous

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Torchinsky's Real Analysis, and am having difficulty demonstrating   if

$$\varphi : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$$ is one-to-one and onto, then it cannot be continuous. (5.13)

Unable to demonstrate this myself, I did some research and found what seems to a proof:

"Suppose such a function exists $$\varphi : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$$

Now, $[0,1]^2 \setminus\{\varphi^{-1}(1/2)\}$ is connected (since $\varphi$ is a bijection we are just removing one point from the square) and by properties of continuous functions we know that $\varphi$ maps connected sets to connected sets (cf. Rudin 4.22) . But $$\varphi\left([0,1]^2 \setminus\{\varphi^{-1}(1/2)\}\right) = [0, 1/2)\cup(1/2, 1]$$ which is not connected, hence no such map can exist."

What is unclear to me: removing point from the domain introduces a discontinuity in the codomain since the function is onto, but how does this prove the assertion for the domain in question: $$ [0,1]^2 \text{ ?}$$

Comment: It does appear that $\varphi^{-1}(1/2)$ must have been intended.  What does $\text{“}\varphi(1/2)\text{''}$ mean when arguments to $\varphi$ are supposed to be ordered pairs? $\qquad$

Comment: Agreed.  I already edited it to reflect this and it appears to currently be sitting in the review queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is saying that if $\phi$ is a continuous bijection from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$, then $\phi$ must satisfy a certain property.  The proof simply uses $[0,1]^2 \setminus \{\phi^{-1}(1/2)\}$ to show that $\phi$ can't possibly have this property.

Here's a breakdown:

1. Let $\phi : [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ be an arbitrary continuous bijection.
2. Because $\phi$ is a bijection, there is a unique point in $[0,1]^2$ such that $\phi^{-1}(1/2)$ corresponds to that point.  So we'll just call it $\phi^{-1}(1/2)$ for clarity.
3. Note that $[0,1]^2 \setminus \{\phi^{-1}(1/2)\}$ is connected because it's a square minus one point.
4. The continuous image of a connected set is connected.  Note that this also means $\phi$ must map any connected *subset* of $[0,1]^2$ to a connected subset of $[0,1]$.
5. Therefore, $\phi\left([0,1]^2 \setminus \{\phi^{-1}(1/2)\}\right)$ must be connected.
6. But because $\phi$ is a bijection, $1/2 \notin \phi\left([0,1]^2 \setminus \{\phi^{-1}(1/2)\}\right)$.
7. So then $\phi\left([0,1]^2 \setminus \{\phi^{-1}(1/2)\}\right) = [0,1/2) \cup (1/2, 1].$
8. $[0,1/2) \cup (1/2, 1]$ is not connected.
9. This shows that if $\phi$ is *any* continuous bijection from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$, then it will map a connected set to a disconnected set.  This is a contradiction.  Therefore there can't possibly be a continuous bijection from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful breakdown.  The note to point 4 was lost on me.  Thanks again.

Comment: Here's proof that a continuous image of a connected set is connected https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected

Comment: The same one I looked at to make sure before I posted this answer :P

Answer (score 1):

We assumed the existence of such a function $\varphi$, did some work to arrive at a contradiction (in particular, the existence of a continuous map that maps a connected set to a set that is *not* connected). Therefore the assumption was not consistent.

The author might have meant $\varphi$ instead of $\varphi^{-1}$. That might have caused confusion.

Comment: Thank you.  (I had an extraneous -1, and have made the edits.)  It's not the proof method that confuses me, but the proof itself - how does proving the existence of such a function on a different domain (i.e. with a point removed) apply to the domain in the question?

Comment: The basic structure of the proof is that of a proof by contradiction. You want to prove the proposition $p$, so you assume $\neg p$. You use $\neg p$ to arrive at $\neg q$ where $q$ is a true proposition. $q \wedge \neg q$ is false, and hence somewhere along the line, an inconsistency was introduced (in our case, $\neg p$).

In this case $p$ is the original claim you are trying to prove. $q$ is the fact that the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected. For an example, see http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/q1.html

Comment: Thank you.  It is not the method of proof, but the proof itself that confuses me.  How does a contradiction for a domain with a point removed apply to the domain in question?

Comment: I'm not sure I can say much more than I have. You should try a few simpler proofs by contradiction. Did you look at the one I linked you to?

Comment: Thank you, I must not be asking my question or responding sufficiently clearly.  The contradiction arrived at is based on a different (as it seems to me) domain (i.e. one with a point removed), so my question isn't about proof by contradiction, but on how the set being used to create the contradiction can be equated with the set in the original question.

Comment: It's not a different domain.  It's the same domain, but the proof is showing that any such $\varphi$ will fail to have a necessary property that it must satisfy for all connected subsets of the domain.  See my answer for more info.